# JQuery won't select sibling elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

With the following code I want a user to click on  tag which is inside li (div ul li a) 
By default, the first  tag has a class 'on'. When is clicked on  tag, the code is supposed to addClass('on') to 'this'  and removeClass('on') from all other  siblings. 
The addClass('on') works, but $(this).siblings().removeClass('on') doesn't work at all.

```
var menu01_list = $(".profile_menu01 ul li > a");

menu01_list.click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('on');
  $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

html code:

```
<div class="profile_menu01">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="btn_my_pick on" href="#">My Pick</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn_my_pickpot" href="#">3<span class="alert_num"></span>My Picpot</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn_my_review" href="#">My ReView</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn_my_photos" href="#">My Photos</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have multiple `profile_menu01` div's having `ul li a` in it? or single `profile_menu01` div exist?

Comment: There's only one single profile_menu01 div with ul li a nested inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the siblings of the `<a>` element - and as they're contained in the `<li>`, there are no siblings. You have to traverse one level up to the `<li>` (and back down) before checking for siblings:

```
menu01_list.click(function(){
   $(this).parent().siblings().children().removeClass('on');
   $(this).addClass('on');
});
```

Alternatively, you can run the function on the li:

```
var menu01_list = $(".profile_menu01 ul li");

menu01_list.click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().children().removeClass('on');
   $(this).children().addClass('on');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your code (`.profile_menu01 ul li > a`), there is no sibling for `a` tag. Use the following code snippets to remove the `on` class.

```
$(this).closest("ul").find("a.on").removeClass("on")
```

**Example:**

```js
 var menu01_list = $(".profile_menu01 ul li > a");

 menu01_list.click(function() {
   $(this).closest("ul").find("a.on").removeClass('on');
   $(this).addClass('on');
 });
```

```css
.on{
  background:Yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile_menu01">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="btn_my_pick on" href="#">My Pick</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn_my_pickpot on" href="#">3<span class="alert_num"></span>My Picpot</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn_my_review on" href="#">My ReView</a></li>
    <li><a class="btn_my_photos on" href="#">My Photos</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made an small mistake on below script,

```
var menu01_list = $(".profile_menu01 ul li > a");

    menu01_list.click(function(){
       $(this).siblings().removeClass('on');
       $(this).addClass('on');
    });
```

on above code you are trying to remove the classes from the `<a>` anchor tag which is not a sibling element because those anchor tags are separated by the parent element `<li>`.

Try below script to **solve you problem**,

```
var menu01_list = $(".profile_menu01 ul li > a");

    menu01_list.click(function(){
       $(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('on');
       $(this).addClass('on');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var menu01_list = $(".profile_menu01 ul li > a");

    menu01_list.click(function(){
       $(this).parent().siblings().children('a').removeClass('on');
       $(this).addClass('on');
    });
```